# How to connect a TFS project to an existing Git repository

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I have my Git account and there I have a repository. After a while I decided to start using [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) to initiate a work tracking process for my team.

However when I create a new project

[image]

And select the `Git` option, a new repository is created. I tried changing the repository, but in the administration tools of the project I can create new repositories.

How can I associate a project to an existing Git repository?

Comment: Where is your existing git repo hosted?

Answer (score 5):

Take your existing repo, add a new remote, and push it.

`git remote add vsts https://<account name>.visualstudio.com/_git/<repo name>`

then

`git push -u vsts --all`

Comment: This is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2015/Visual Studio 2015 [would manage its own Git repos](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/repo-rename).

So try instead to push your existing repo to that new one, instead of making TFS reference your previous remote repo.

As mentioned in "[Creating Git repositories with Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/creatingrepo)":

> You can also create a local repository from a local folder using Git's init command and then push the repo to Team Services.